# What to call a library of shared libraries in programming

Tags: word-usage, terminology, programming, computing

There are (for example) three *dynamic libraries* that is files `libxx.so`, `libyy.so`, and `libzz.so` (or `.dll` files `xx.dll`, `yy.dll`, and `zz.dll` on Windows).

What do you call the collection of all three files (as well the entire source code from which the three files are generated)? It is commonly called library, but to say "the library consisting of three libraries" is so to say inconvenient.

Also note that every library may consist of several *modules*.

Comment: DLL's is the word I use- "Dynamic Linking Libraries." Are you referring to API's?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Requests for terminology used in specific sectors are typically better-asked of subject matter experts. I would expect even a beginner software developer or desktop support specialist to produce a more reliable answer than the average English teacher or linguistics professor.

Comment: @choster Not all of us are English teachers or linguistics professors, though.

Comment: Runtime support package, Runtime environment, shared object collection...  As Ian says, it really depends on their relationship to each other and to the application(s) that link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on their relationship with one another and their completeness-of-purpose, you may be able to use the word ***framework***.

> **framework** *noun*
>   frame·​work | \ˈfrām-ˌwərk  \
>   Definition of framework
>   1a : a basic conceptional structure (as of ideas)
>   the framework of the U.S. Constitution
>   These influences threaten the very framework of our society.
>   b : a skeletal, openwork, or structural frame
>   An iron framework surrounds the sculpture.
>   2 : FRAME OF REFERENCE
>   3 : the larger branches of a tree that determine its shape
>   <sub>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/framework</sub>